# Adding a reference in VS2010

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm trying to follow this tutorial for an Accordion control in WPF:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/538/

I am not super familiar with VS.  I'm running VS2010, I right click on the Reference->Add Reference, go to the .NET tab, and I do not see any System.Windows.Controls.  Am I missing something in order to follow this tutorial?  Thanks.

Comment: Look in your project properties. What is the framework version? If you were set to 2.0, then you wouldn't see `System.Windows.Controls`.

Comment: @John Saunders: Says .net Framework 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to add a reference to a custom DLL form the WPF toolkit.  To do this you will need to browse to the DLL on disk.

- Select "Add Reference" from the project menu
- Click on the Browse Tab
- Navigate to the DLL on disk
- Select it and hit OK

Comment: Is that a custom DLL from the WPF toolkit?  I'm new to the whole VS/WPF world.  So is that some add-on I download separately?  Thx.

Comment: @Crystal that appears to be the case from the blog post referenced in your question. I believe you can download the latest version here: http://wpf.codeplex.com/